# Android Lag in udp transmission

Tags: java, android, network-programming, udp, android-networking

I have a problem with lag in udp transmission (over a **local wifi network**). The host sends data to all clients using UdpSender at 50Hz :

UDPSender:

```
public class UDPSender {

    private DatagramSocket socket;

    private DatagramPacket packet;

    private ByteBuffer bb;

    private InetAddress targetAddress;

    private byte[] bytearray;

    public UDPSender(int port,String targetAddress){
        try {
            this.targetAddress =  InetAddress.getByName(targetAddress);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        }
        try {
            socket = new DatagramSocket();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(169);
        bytearray = bb.array();
        packet = new DatagramPacket(bytearray, bytearray.length, this.targetAddress, port);
    }


    public void sendSignal(/*args*/){
        if(!socket.isClosed()){
            bb.putInt(pos, ...)   //fill 'bb' with data from args
                    ...
            bytearray = bb.array();
            packet.setData(bytearray);
            try {
                socket.send(packet);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }   
    }
    public void close(){
        socket.close();
    }

}
```

UDPReceiver:

```
public class UDPReceiver {

    private DatagramSocket socket;

    private DatagramPacket packet;

    private byte[] packetDataBuffer = new byte[169];

    private UDPSignalListener listener = null;

    private ByteBuffer bb;

    private String hostAddress;

    private boolean isOpen = false;

    private byte buffer;

    private short bytes;

    public UDPReceiver(int port, String hostAddress, UDPSignalListener listener){
        try {
            socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if(listener!=null)
                listener.errorOpeningSocket(port);
        }
        packet = new DatagramPacket(packetDataBuffer, packetDataBuffer.length);
        this.hostAddress = hostAddress;
        this.listener = listener;
        isOpen = true;
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                listen();
            }

        });
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();

    }

    public void start(String hostAddress){
        this.hostAddress = hostAddress;
        isOpen = true;
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                listen();
            }

        });
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();
    }

    private void listen(){
        while(isOpen){
            try {
                socket.receive(packet);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                continue;
            }
            if(!isOpen)
                return;
            if(packet.getAddress().getHostAddress().equals(hostAddress)){
                bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(packetDataBuffer);
                //read data from bb
                if(listener!=null)
                    listener.onSignalRecieved(/*pass data to program*/);
            }    
        }
    }

    public int getPort(){
        return socket.getLocalPort();
    }
    public void close(){
        isOpen = false;
        socket.close();
    }

}
```

MainThread on host-side:

```
mainThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            while(isMainLoopRunning){ 
                ...
                for(int i=0;i<udpSender.length/*max 5*/;++i)
                    udpSender[i].sendSignal(...);  //~50fps constantly //send data to client i
                ...
            }
        }
});
```

the client side gets the data via UDPSignalListener.onSignalReceived() (should be called every 20ms (50fps)). The data is saved and is used in the client's mainThread (which also runs at 50fps constantly). Unfortunately there is sometimes a lag (a delay up to 1 second), i.e onSignalReceived is not called every 20ms constantly. What could be the reason for the lag?

Comment: Are you testing this on Android device internally or emulator or over a network on two different devices?

Comment: on different android devices. While it works ok on two devices it works badly on 6(max number of devices) devices..

Comment: When using mutiple devices, you need handle your cases of ACK so that you know each device Rx UDP datagram. If it helps you could use MulticastUDP on Android.

Comment: Unfortunately, multicast is not supported by all android devices.
But, knowing whether the clients received the datagram doesn't correct the lag-problem..?